# Change default "tab" action (transferfocus)

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtextfield

in Java `SWING` the "*Tab*" `key` globally transfers the `focus` between all `components`. Is it possible to modify this "*default*" behavior somehow?

So instead of having the "*Tab*" `key` change the `focus`, I want the "*Enter*" key doing it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to change the focusTraversalSystem takes a lot of work to do. I suggest to add an actionListener on the panel  where it holds all the swing components and check the key pressed if it is enter just change the focus on the next element that has the tabFocus variable + 1( you need to put the components in an array to loop or use a native swing method if applicable).

Comment: Sad that it is that difficult to change such a little thing :/ Anyway, I'm aware of that solution - thanks anyway. I'll use that now!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that by using

1) `KeyBindings` you can do that very easy and most safest way

2) you can get last `Component`, J/Component with `Focus` in the Window from method  `Component#getOppositeComponent()`

no `Array` or `SwingUtilities` required, maybe `Z-Order` can do that by default, but not suported for all `Look and Feels`